# Can someone explain the language L = {w: w = uu, u \in La(1*01*)}

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

[image]

I need help understanding the language `L` above.

These are my understanding: 
- `w = uu` is a concatenation of `u` 
- `La(1*01*)` can be expressed in regular language i.e. `r1 = 1*01*` so `La(r1)` 
- also we have regular expression property of concatenation: `L(r1r2) = L(r1)L(r2)`

So base on my understanding the language `L` can be simplified to 
[image]

I'm not quite sure about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your simplification is wrong.

Consider, as a simpler case, $A=\{a,b\}$ and $L'=\{ w \mid w=uu , u\in A\}$. Then, $L'=\{aa,bb\}$.

Instead, if we apply your simplification and write $L''=AA$ then we have $L''=\{aa,ab,ba,bb\}$ which is a larger language, since we forgot that both $u$'s in $w=uu$ must be the *same* word.

Keeping that into account, your original language $L$ seems to be $\{1^n01^m1^n01^m \mid n,m\geq 0 \}$

Comment: So we ignored `ab` and `ba` in the set because `uu` is an element of `A` and must be the same character.

Comment: @tramyardg It must be the same word, repeated. In this case $A$ only contains single-letter words, but in general it can contain longer words, as in your example.